Cypress component testing fails because of tailwind
I am trying to do some component testing with Cypress and I can't get it to work, I am always getting an error.

I think this is happening because Tailwind is not set up correctly. I tried following multiple guides online including the one from cypress themselves but I can't get it to work.
My test:
import React from 'react';
import MyComponent from "./page";

describe('render', () => {
    it('renders', () => {
        cy.mount(<MyComponent/>)
    })
})

Component:
export default function MyComponent() {
  return (
     <div className="relative isolate">
        <div className="mx-auto grid max-w-7xl grid-cols-1">
           Hello
        </div>
     </div>
   )
}

cypress.config.js:
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress');

module.exports = defineConfig({
    component: {
        supportFile: 'cypress/support/component.js',
        devServer: {
            framework: 'next',
            bundler: 'webpack',
        },
    },
})

cypress/support/component.js:
import "tailwindcss/tailwind.css";

I also tried compiling css using tailwindcss -i src/app/globals.css -o src/index.css and including index.css but that didn't change anything either.
I tried testing a component that does not use tailwind in any way and it works so the issue is definitely with tailwind.
What am I missing?
The app is set up using Next if that matters.

Please provide a reproducible example. The Cypress example app listed below works.

this is a reproducible example, that's my current setup and it doesn't work for me

How is it reproducible, since you haven't posted the component? How can we compare to the published Cypress example?

I added a component to the question. I haven't posted it because it doesn't really matter what component I am testing. Once I add tailwind classes it fails. If I remove those classes it works just fine.

The cause may be that Tailwind code needs to be compiled, but component testing does not have the compilation steps of a full app.
Looking at cypress-component-testing-apps repo (the react-cra4-js example) they have a script in package.json to pre-compile the CSS.
"scripts": {
  ...
  "compile:css": "tailwindcss -i src/tailwind.css -o src/index.css",

Then the compiled index.css is imported in cypress/support/component.js
// Import commands.js using ES2015 syntax:
import './commands'

// Ensure global app styles are loaded:
import '../../src/index.css';                <-- after running compile:css script

import { mount } from 'cypress/react'

Cypress.Commands.add('mount', mount)

This seems to be a fairly simple way of by-passing the Tailwind compilation step inside the test.

Your component and test
I added Tailwind bg color and text color for more obvious effect,
export default function MyComponent() {
  return (
     <div className="relative isolate">
        <h1 className="mx-auto grid max-w-7xl grid-cols-1 bg-cy-blue text-white">
           Hello
        </h1>
     </div>
   )
}

import React from 'react'
import MyComponent from './my-component'

describe('render', () => {
  it('renders', () => {
    cy.mount(<MyComponent />)
    cy.get('h1')
      .should('have.text', 'Hello')
      .and('have.css', 'background-color', 'rgb(73, 86, 227)')  // a slightly saturated medium violet
  })
})


This is the imported CSS (into /cypress/support/component.ts)
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap');

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;


But wouldn’t importing tailwind.css from tailwindcss node module be enough?

also, same error. It just has index.css in the stack trace now: at push../src/index.css.options.insert (webpack://_N_E/./src/index.css?9f38:21)...

what the hell...I went through your update. It exactly matches my setup
